# In SQL, how to join multiple foreign keys IDs in multiple columns of a table to a single primary key in another table and uniquely select one?

Tags: sql, left-join, multiple-columns, exists

**Table A:** Patient Encounters With Linked Diagnoses(DX)

| Encounter_ID | Date | Primary_DX | DX_2 | DX_3 | DX_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 01/01/2020 | 234234 | 256756 | 254537 | 678688 |
| 11112 | 05/01/2020 | 344564 | 234553 | 6786667 | 234234 |
| 11113 | 01/01/2022 | 123233 | 656444 | 678688 | 535465 |
| 11114 | 01/01/2021 | 435345 | 666654 | 3453453 | 456448 |

**Table B**: Diagnoses(DX) Code Linked with Their respective ICD Code

NOTE: The codes for this table is filtered for `DX_ID`/`ICD_CODE`'s specifically for heart disease.

| DX_ID | ICD_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 234234 | N123.42 |
| 344564 | N45.32 |
| 234553 | N153.24 |
| 678688 | N365.34 |

I seek to get only the **encounters** with the following condition:

At least one of the Primary_DX, DX_2,DX_3,DX_4 codes in Table A is a heart disease, that is, their respective diagnosis code can be linked to table B.

From this list, I seek to *only get the ICD_Code for only that heart disease diagnosis code*.

I have to do this in two steps:

1. Get all encounters where at least one of the `DX_code` in Table A is a `DX_Code` in Table B.
2. From this temporary table, select only the heart disease code and retrieve the `ICD_code`. If there are multiple heart disease for a single encounter, then they will show up as two separate rows.

So final output could have the following format:

| Encounter_ID | ICD_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | N123.42 |
| 11111 | N45.32 |
| 11112 | N123.42 |
| 11115 | N15.42 |
| 11114 | N123.42 |

Now filter for heart disease dx_codes with the `EXISTS` cause as below:

```
SELECT
    Enounter_ID,
    Primary_DX,
    DX_2,
    DX_3,
    DX_4,
FROM 
    TABLE_A
WHERE   
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_B)
```

But I am getting encounters where NONE of the linked diagnoses are from the heart disease table.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. PS "I think" is frequently a euphemism for "I don't think & I'm not sure", a euphemism for "I don't know". If you think something, just say it. If you don't think it, don't you think it. If you're not sure, you don't know. If you don't know, say you don't know. Always, give your reasoning. Waffling impedes reasoning, communication & solving.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be enough ?

```
select Encounter_ID, ICD_CODE 
  from Table_A, Table_B
 where Primary_DX = DX_ID
    or DX_2 = DX_ID
    or DX_3 = DX_ID
    or DX_4 = DX_ID
order by Encounter_ID
```